# spark broadcast variable not serializable exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, notserializableexception

I want to use an Rtree like https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree2 as a spark broadcast variable.

However, `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.github.davidmoten.rtree2.RTree` it is not supported.

Is there a workaround? https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree2 suggestes:

```
/ deserialize the entries from disk (for example)
List<Entry<Thing, Point> entries = ...
// bulk load
RTree<Thing, Point> tree = RTree.maxChildren(28).star().create(entries);
```

But I do not know how to fit this in the context of the broadcast variable. I.e. I certainly could broadcast the list of entries, but I do not know an entry point in initializing the Rtree then on all the executors when using a UDF.
Certainly, it should be possible via map-partitions, but I would by far prefer the UDF approach.

```
import com.github.davidmoten.grumpy.core.Position
  import com.github.davidmoten.rtree2.geometry.{Geometries, Point}
  import com.github.davidmoten.rtree2.{Entry, Iterables, RTree}

  val sydney = Geometries.point(151.2094, -33.86)
  val canberra = Geometries.point(149.1244, -35.3075)
  val brisbane = Geometries.point(153.0278, -27.4679)
  val bungendore = Geometries.point(149.4500, -35.2500)

  var tree = RTree.star.create[String, Point]
  tree = tree.add("Sydney", sydney)
  tree = tree.add("Brisbane", brisbane)

  val broadcastVar = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(tree)
```

this fails with the aforementioned exception.

By the way this also applies to:

- https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree

  RTree tree = ...;
  OutputStream os = ...;
  Serializer serializer = 
    Serializers.flatBuffers().utf8();
  serializer.write(tree, os); 
  apparently this should work, but at least for spark it will not work with the same exception

### edit 2

Workaround:

Using something like https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/rtree2d which properly supports serialization. Nonetheless it would be interesting how to retrofit it to the first example.